# Square brackets around variable name (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, syntax

Can somebody explain, what this line of code represents in Javascript:

`const [m, o] = [player.matrix, player.pos]`

Im specifically confused by the square brackets around variable names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what we call a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), you are effectively doing this:

```
const m = player.matrix;
const o = player.pos;
```

Note that this syntax is part of the **ECMAScript 2015** (6th Edition, ECMA-262) standard and is not immediately available to all browser implementations. You can read more about it [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-destructuring-assignment).

There is also a [compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-destructuring,_assignment) that you can check.

Comment: Remove comma after `matrix`

Comment: Also note that the functionality of descructing assignments is only supported by [ECMAScript 6 or newer](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-destructuring,_assignment)

Comment: @chade_ Added note and link to official Ecma docs. Thanks.

Comment: How about in this case?:
const [wordToReplace] = myArr.filter(item => item === before);

Comment: @Netside The 'wordToReplace' variable will now contain the first item in the resulting array. Consider starting a new question or searching for a similar one for a more complete answer though.